# How to send data to mobile device with OneSignal without showing notification?

Tags: onesignal

I want to send a json string to my app with OneSignal, but I don't want a notification to be shown.

Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

add this line in application.java where onesignal in initializing:

```
.setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
```

so you should have sth like this:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();
```

create ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler class:

```
public class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
@Override
public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {

    JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
    String datavalue;


    if (data != null) {
        datavalue = data.optString("datakey", null);
        //do what ever you want with value
     }
```

}

you should send backround data using "Additional Data" section from onesignal new notification page, and dont forget to turn on "Background data"

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called Silent Notifications.

> Silent Notifications are background notifications that do not show any message on the device.

where

> Background notifications are designed to keep your app's data up-to-date by providing a way to "wake up" the app to refresh the data in the background.

You'll need to [Send a Silent Notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications#section-sending-silent-notifications) and then override `onNotificationProcessing` method on the client side, where you can retrieve the data and return true to stop the notification from displaying.

check out the documentations on [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding).